# Using the results of clustering to retrain a neural network

Tags: clustering, convolutional-neural-network, pytorch, feature-extraction, retraining

I am following and expanding upon previous work from the winner of the [Melanoma Classification](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/siim-isic-melanoma-classification/overview) from [here](https://github.com/haqishen/SIIM-ISIC-Melanoma-Classification-1st-Place-Solution).

The dataset has 9 classes. The competition is only interested in the one class (Melanoma).

I have taken the feature outputs (pre-final layer) from CNN and performed clustering. Then used this to group different classes (leaving Melanoma as its own group) then used this in the training.

I have already performed clustering with other steps (PCA, TSNE, K-Means, Hierarchichal, LDA, QDA, NDA, etc.) and have results. I am largely trying to understand the maths (and background research) behind why this approach in retraining might improve performance (on the ROC-AUC of the class that was not grouped ie. melanoma)

Any advice / relevant papers welcome!

Thanks,

Comment: I will come back to answer this with more time. Here are some initial thoughts: Yes this is a very common approach. Generate embeddings from an image/text/dataset, then perform some form of clutering/similarity measure on the embeddings. You need a similarity metric (e.g. cosine similarity), and a clustering method - default to K-means, and add query expansion.

Comment: Are you aware of the paper written by the winner? https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2215016120300832?via%3Dihub Why not just use that and follow references?

Comment: and this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07479v1.pdf

Comment: Hi GooJ neither paper references clustering and unfortunately I dont have more time to perform additional training, thanks though.

Comment: I don't understand why you've mentioned clustering because it is never mentioned in the paper. Have I misunderstood the paper or are you applying clustering for result interpretability? In all cases, dim reduction has always interesting views, which results might help tune the NN training approaches. For instance, defining better learning rates or L2 parameters. Is it this kind of approach you would like to understand?

Comment: @NicolasMartin Yeah sorry if not clear, im using their paper as a base then doing extra work on top (i.e. the clustering and retraining)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with [Brian's answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/114250/100269) in the following sense:

All the steps you perform ie embedding, clustering, retraining,.. do not represent, in principle, qualitatively different math operations than what a dedicated deep model with non-linearities can do.

So, in this sense, I do not expect to get radically different performance than using a single NN model trained end-to-end.

That being said, whatever approach one uses (as I expect them to be equivalent) one will possibly have to deal with class imbalance wisely.

Comment: Yes class imbalance is one of they key aspects of this challenge, mostly I have just used external data to supplement the proportion of melanoma (like many in the challenge) up to 9% representation. My general thoughts are that the more class labels that are used as targets in training the stronger connections can be made for that specific class thereby lessening the error in other classes hence the head-scratching why I would be recommended this approach by a professor (who is yet to clarify why).

Answer (score 3):

Clustering might not be useful since the goal is improving a supervised learning metric (ROC-AUC) and all the data already has labels.

It might be better to manually create Melanoma / Not Melanoma categories based on existing labels and then build an end-to-end deep learning system with multi-model information. This would automatically learn to weight the most important features for the task.

Comment: So I have used the results from the clustering (eg 3 clusters (targets 1,2,3)(targets 4,5,6,7)(melanoma)) and used these 'cluster labels' as the ground truth labels in the neural network training (with an imagenet pretrained model as base). One of the models is binary like you have suggested. Multiple people are performing this binary method but not clarifying why they are using that over the 9 target classes available.

Answer (score 1):

Applying dimensional reduction could help understand why the neural network has made classifications, but we have to deep dive into the results using analytics.

In this [example](https://umap-tour.github.io/resnet50.html) from Restnet50, you can see the UMAP result at each step. If you take the flattened one, you can see some outliers in different clusters. You would have something similar for the Melona classification.

The advantage of using UMAP is to detect why some classifications are wrong and why they are far from their correct cluster.

Therefore, you can get the ranges of each cluster (min and max values) and compare them with the wrong classified results.

For instance, if there is a wrongly classified melanoma in a cluster and you find out that the age was very different from the other cluster's age, you might emphasize the "age weight" with a power factor.

Unfortunately, it could be quite complex to do because all features are inter-dependants, and modifying one feature could have unforeseeable impacts on the others.

That's why many researchers try many potential solutions and choose the best one, without having a rigorous scientific approach because of the noise in the human-made data and the important quantity of learning iterations + the use of different modules.

In conclusion, applying dim reduction could give you a better understanding of a model and find new ideas to improve it thanks to the clusters' organization (overall in UMAP, where there is meaningful logic between clusters places), but such improvement could be very complex and could require many trials and fails.

Here are interesting articles about NN interpretability:

https://www.kaggle.com/code/subinium/interpretable-cnn-with-shap-mnist

https://towardsdatascience.com/dense-or-convolutional-part-2-interpretability-c310a9fd99a5

In this picture, you can see that UMAP has meaningful placement between clusters.
[image]

Comment: You are definitely correct about UMAP / tsne, I did my own exploration in TSNE and discovered an outlier cluster of melanoma. See the images in the main cluster of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adbandy/data_files/main/target_6_pca_tsne_main_cluster.png compared to the rogue cluster of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adbandy/data_files/main/target_6_pca_tsne_outliers.png for instance if you were curious

Comment: About UMAP, it is better to see the images in the 2D projected space instead of a grid, so that you see how far the outliers are from their correct cluster.